# Null output in using class methods

Tags: c++, templates

In following code I get no output from directly calling sumit() function, but when I call it through the other function displayIt() (which calls sumit() ), it displays the output. How can I fix it? And please also explain what is happening?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


template <typename C>

class ABC
{

private:
  C num1, num2;

public:
  ABC(C a, C b)
  {
      num1 = a;
      num2 = b;
  }

void displayIt()
  {
      cout << "A+B:" << sumit() << endl;
  }

C sumit() { return num1 + num2; }

};

int main()
{
ABC<int> o1(2, 3);
ABC<string> o2("ABC", "XYZ");

//It doesn't display aything...
cout << "Call-1: " << endl;
o1.sumit();
o2.sumit();

//It displays the output...
cout << "Call-2: " << endl;
o1.displayIt();
o2.displayIt();

system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Can you spot the difference between `sumit()` and `cout << sumit()`?

Comment: Why would you expect something to appear on screen if you don't use `std::cout` at all in `sumit`? It's like writing `1+1;` on a separate line and expecting `2` to appear on screen. It's not how C++ works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you get no output , because this method isn't trying to print anything . It simply returns a number.

Either do this in main :

```
cout << o1.sumit() << endl;
cout << o2.sumit() << endl;
```

Which will directly print the value returned from this method.

Or add the same logic of `displayIt` to `sumit` .

**BTW** - This question is irrelevant to C++ Template . The same behaviour would have happened in a regular class .